# Как закрыть порт 5432?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Запущена postgresql 9.5 на Debian 8, php обращается к базе через юникс-сокет, администрирование - командная строка (psql), в общем, открытый порт не нужен, можно ли его закрыть средствами самой постгри, без Iptables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите в конфиге

```
listen_addresses = ''
```

Тогда postgresql не будет биндить tcp сеть, даже localhost. За unix-сокет отвечает отдельная настройка `unix_socket_directories`

Comment: Yep! Заработало, и шел я в правильном направлении, но просто закомментировать строку listen_addresses = 'localhost' почему-то оказалось недостаточно, а вот listen_addresses = '' - это сработало, спасибо.

Comment: `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` как раз подразумевается в дефолте, если настройка в конфиге или аргументах запуска никакая указана не была.